# How to creating a link within an email to a java program with parameters

Tags: java, parameters, hyperlink, args

Within my hospital I wish to send an email to staff members with a link which when clicked will run a Java app which displays a form to be completed. I have got this working for a standard form requesting their details. However I need to be able to provide a link with a parameter. I have tried:

1. \location\program.jar param
2. \location\program.jar?param
3. \location\program.jar%20param

All give a "Cannot open the specified file." message.
Without the parameter works fine.
Must be possible surely?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are using JavaMail :

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(html, "UTF-8", "html");
```